# Convert string from one date format to another

Tags: c#, .net, date

I am trying to convert `2014-12-25` (yyyy-mm-dd), to `December 25, 2014`. What is the best practice on how to do this?  I currently have it stored in a variable because they are choosing the date from a date picker, but I am displaying that value somewhere else on the page and want it in the above format.

Code:

```
myLabel.Text = "Period: " + FromDate + " to " + ToDate;
```

The from and to date are the two variables holding the date from the datepicker. I need help on converting it to `December 25, 2014`

Comment: Are your variables string or DateTime?

Comment: they are string @MihaiCaracostea

Comment: The goal of this was actually to see how many down votes a question could get. Doing good so far @JeremyThompson

Comment: _I want a [packet of Tim Tams that never runs out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoggSVxghWs)_ . Welcome to SO. Please don't post requirements and like Tim Tims, expect code to magically appear. Any code to show? What research have you done? Good luck!   (the code you are showing at the moment has nothing to do with conversion so it arguably does not count)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Edit:

Since your variables are string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

That would give you the conversion of formats from your string datetime to the one you want.

Comment: so i could do, FromDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")  ? FromDate is already is String. I don't think it will like that

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
```

See "[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

```
myLabel.Text = "Period: " + FromDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + " to " + ToDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: So, why the downvote? Is my answer misleading?

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but your answer only works if the OP's variables are dates, which he has added they are not.

Comment: Not dv either. But you should provide an explanation, or at least link to the documentation....

Answer (score 1):

if you have "2014-12-25" in string variable you should parse it first and convert it to a `DateTime`

```
 var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
```

but if you have "2014-12-25" already in a `DateTime` variable it is just a matter of formatting. just use

```
 Console.WriteLine(FromDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
```

[list of date time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)